# Is there a way to open just the Python IDLE editor (without starting a python console session)?

Tags: python-2.7, python-idle

I like the basic text formatting of the IDLE editor, but I want to use JupyterQtConsole as my console. Can I specify that I don't want a console started when I invoke IDLE? (or is that what the radio buttons in the General settings of IDLE are meant to do)?

Comment: i know is not 100% what you asked, but have you tried using other editors like SublimeText or Atom?

Comment: @le_vine I've heard sublime is pretty cool. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are several ways to start Idle with an edit window.

1. The General option radio buttons, as you noted.

In console, with python 3.x:

2a. `python -m idlelib <filename>`

2b. `python -m idlelib -e`  (use -h for all options)

3. In Windows, right click, select `Edit with Idle`